# Java Object Serialization... is it redundant and robust?

Tags: java, serialization

I have a couple of things that I would like some clarification about:

Object serialization is pretty handy when storing otherwise hard-to-store data. You use a class with a SerialVersionUUID and then you can read & write it around. What if:

1. I add a new variable in the serializable class so that the old serializable objects don't have this variable? Will it still load and leave the variable uninitialized or will it throw an Exception, making the serialized objects unusable?
2. What if I change the SerialVersionUUID? The "outdated" serialized objects will no longer load? Is there a way to convert them easily or would there be a custom system in place to do that?
3. What if I change a variable type that exists already? There might be a casting exception?
4. Are there any alternatives to saving big serializable classes in a way that the data will not become corrupt if the "model" (being the serializable class) is altered?

Thanks in advance for answering this. I apologize if the questions are bad. They just came to my mind and I would like to know more about it.

After looking around for posting etiquette asking multiple questions in one post is not forbidden nor frowned upon. The only risk is getting incorrect answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Java Object Serialization... is it redundant

No.

> and robust?

It is reasonably robust against class versioning within the constraints defined in its specification. For any other value of 'robust' you need to define your terms.

> 1. I add a new variable in the serializable class so that the old serializable objects don't have this variable? Will it still load and leave the variable uninitialized or will it throw an Exception, making the serialized objects unusable?

It will leave the variable uninitialized.

> 2. What if I change the SerialVersionUUID?

It will throw `InvalidClassException.`

> The "outdated" serialized objects will no longer load?

See above.

> Is there a way to convert them easily or would there be a custom system in place to do that?

No. Moral: don't change the `serialVersionUID`. Contrary to a lot of well-meaning but uninformed opinion you will find on the Internet, that suggests for example changing it on every revision. ***Never*** change it unless you ***specifically*** want to cause `InvalidClassException`.

> 3. What if I change a variable type that exists already? There might be a casting exception?

It will throw an exception. You can't change the type of serializable member variables.

> 4. Are there any alternatives to saving big serializable classes in a way that the data will not become corrupt if the "model" (being the serializable class) is altered?

You need to study the [Versioning chapter of the Object Serialization Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/platform/serialization/spec/version.html), where all these questions are answered.